# rename files on server cpanel jailshell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, jail-shell

Im trying to rename files on my server to remove special characters (whitespace, æøå, etc) from the filenames. The problem is that i cannot get the rename-function to work. On my local machine the rename function works as expected

```
rename 's/[^a-zA-Z\.0-9]*/_/g' *.mp3
```

renames all files and removes special characters.

On the server, however, the above call has no effect whatsoever. ALso, there is no error message. There is no man-pages-available for the rename-function on the server, and when I try

```
rename --help
call: rename from to files...
```

...the helpfull message "rename from to files" ...

Any suggestions? The shell on the server (running ) is some sort of jailshell, the server is running parallells - stuff and cpanel (if that helps)... regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script called `renamer.sh`:

```
dname=$(dirname "$1")
bname=$(basename "$1")
clean=$(tr -dc 'a-zA-Z.0-9' <<< "$bname")
mv "$1" "$dname/$clean"
```

And use `find`:

```
find -type f -name '*.mp3' -exec sh renamer.sh {} \;
```

Comment: However, it would be great if someone knew something about how todays rename-function on my system actually works?

Comment: @jonasfh, you want the Perl script called rename, not the binary you have installed. Check this out: http://superuser.com/a/302393

Comment: Hi,  i took the perl-script and copied it to the bin-folder in my home-folder with the name prename, so now I can use it like the normal rename-function. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

@jonasfh: The cpanel jailshell is usually installed on top of centos hosts.
Now you can look up rename from the redhat util-linux package, which is not the usual perl script with extended regular expressions you are trying to do, just the simple redhat rename.